# Address Bar and Google Search lead to different websites for the same URL

Tags: google-search, redirects, dns, spam

How is it possible that the same URL, when typed in the address bar, leads to a different website, when searched for in Google leads to a different one?

Example:

If you type in `mdgpartners.com` in the address bar it will lead to the correct website.

If you search for `mdg partners` in Google, and click on the first link (with the same URL `mdgpartners.com`) it leads to a spam/junk website.

The domain is registered by GoDaddy for the original website, a reverse lookup on Google's DNS leads to the correct IP address. But the link from the search goes haywire.

How does one remedy this?

Comment: That sounds like a hacked site to me.  There is probably something in the .htaccess file or other server config that is detecting traffic from Google and hijacking it.   Google maintains a guide to help: https://developers.google.com/webmasters/hacked/

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the website might be hacked and the unwanted version is only shown when the referrer (previous page) is Google. Based on what's in the Google Cache (http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:Opw5wKNhVJMJ:www.mdgpartners.com/%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us) it seems that yet another version of the website is shown to GoogleBot.

When I create a test.html file on desktop and add a link to your website it returns the normal website so it doesn't seem related to 'links' in general.

I guess serving the hacked website like this helps to reduce the detection rate for webmasters as they usually type in their own website name directly, while other people visit the website through links on Google?

**Try contacting your web host to see if there are any signals of a hack, and if so, revert to a backup after fully cleaning up your account.**